# Reset styles in react component

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I want to reset all styles in my react component, something I used to do with this:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I am using scss modules `componentname.module.scss`. So if I do like the code above, it will reset the styles to all elements on the page.

Is there a way to reset styles only to elements of my react component?

Answer (score 0):

You could give all your components a shared class or ID name and set your style preferences on that.

Comment: isn't there a way to do rather than to add unnecessary class names to my elements just to reset?